# Nginx adds www to the header host

Tags: nginx, nginx-ingress

```
location / {
    proxy_set_header Host sub.domain.host.com;
    proxy_pass https://other.host.com/;
}
```

The host header ends up being **www**.sub.domain.host.com, is there a way to prevent the **www** from being added?

Comment: Don't type it in to the configuration.

Comment: Are you sure the server does it and not some lousy browser?